# Does a dwang/blocking qualify as "protection" for non-finished walls?

Tags: wiring, nec, protection

The NEC stipulates that all wire running horizontally between studs must be protected.  My understanding is that wire that runs *vertically* down a stud can be stapled to the center of the stud and that is classified as "protected" (could be wrong though).  If I install a [dwang or blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwang) between my studs (horizontally) and staple a cable to the bottom center of that blocking, does that too qualify as protected?

For clarity, this is for open, non-closed walls.

Comment: The stapling is not for nail protection, but for preventing movement and therefore fraying. The actual protection is because the wiring is recessed enough that nails won't hit it. I think that as long as the horizontal run is recessed enough you don't need metal plates, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: You are discussing open studs here, correct? No finish layer of drywall/plywood? I think I recall that from other questions, but that's a detail this question needs for the right answers, since with a finish layer it can simply be run between holes in the center of the studs and be fine.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Per the title: non-finished walls ;)  
Updated for clarity.

Comment: "Dwang" according to your link (thank you!) is _not_ a US term, yet you refer to [tag:nec]. Can you please clarify that this _is_ in the US, as your local codes may be different if you're not.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, in the US.  dwang is the term that I learned to call this (thanks to a Kiwi)...and I *think* this is called a blocking the US, but I'm not sure.  Hence the link for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEC requires the cable to be 1-1/4” back from the face of the stud. If it is not a nail plate is required. Code requires the cable to be protected in the stud bay by 1/2” plywood or sheetrock. This is normally required to a height of 8’(some inspectors allow 7’ the height is not specifically listed in code but protected by elevation at 8’ is listed so most use that)
It may look funny for the 1 bay to be closed in but these are the 2 requirements.

Comment: Really?  I thought you only had to "protect" the cable if it ran horizontally between studs.  You're saying that all cable, whether running vertically or horizontally, stapled to the stud or not, needs the 1/2" plywood or sheetrock?  I take your word for it, but I'm confused because the house we had built in 2005 had open walls in the garage with cable stapled to the studs (not protected).  Maybe that area had different requirements.

Comment: A wire running down a stud is exposed to physical damage. NEC 334.17 through or parallel to framing members comply with 300.4 protection against physical damage normally has to be protected to a height of 8’ code says they shall be protected if you have a work bench and are hammering on something and a piece flys off and hits the cable it can be damaged and present a hazard this is why most jurisdictions require protection up to 8’ I was told this comes from 110.27 guarding of live parts a minimum of 8’ for 50 to 300v I believe this and possibly 1 other similar are the 8’ rules that AHJ  uses.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with that.  That's what I expected, and it makes sense, I just cannot reconcile it with how our house was built 15 years ago (we no longer live there).  Maybe it was just done wrong.  Thanks for the feedback and code references.  This has been very helpful!

Comment: Some areas I have worked do not require the nmb to be covered. This was more common in my apprenticeship and early years in the 70’s. Some areas require conduit or 1/2 plywood or Sheetrock it really varies my last 3 locations all required it to be covered below 8’.